# Node js relationship beetwen vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, nodes

I have variable partner_id.

```
data() {
    return {
      form: {
        partner_id: "",
      }
     }
}
```

I need to update partner_id if select2 input is changed. Like this:

```
 mounted() {
        $('.select2').select2();
        $('.select2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
            this.form.partner_id= e.params.data.id;
        });
}
```

But I cant get partner_id from this method. How can I update partner_id? Im new in Node Js and sure I'm missing something

Comment: keyword "this" inside your jquery on event is referring to the $(".select2") not your data I think you can use form directly try form.partnet_id